# Join three tables and display in gridview as per condition

Tags: sql, ms-access

In my Access database I am trying to display data from three tables:

1. PERS
2. COURSE
3. WORKED

I want all rows from `PERS` and some matching fields from `COURSE` and `WORKED`. `KNO` is the common field in all tables

eg : SELECT [KNO], [Name], [Company], [Location], [State] FROM [Pers]

```
  If the KNo had done CCNA (Course.Qualification)

  if he had Worked in Channai or Kolkatta or in Bangalore (Worked.Coyloc)
```

then only show

I used :

```
Select 
     Pers.KNO, Pers.Name, Pers.Company, Pers.Location, Pers.State 
from Pers 
left join (Course on pers.KNo=Course.KNO) 
left join Worked.KNo=Per.KNO 
where 
     Course.Qualification='CCNA' 
    and (Worked.Coyloc='Bangalore' or Worked.Coyloc='Channai or Worked.Coyloc='Kolkatta')
```

I am having trouble adding the [Worked] table to the query. When I just include [Pers] and [Course] I get the results I expect.

```
Select 
   Pers.KNO, Pers.Name, Pers.Company, Pers.Location, Pers.State 
from Pers 
left join Course 
   on pers.KNo=Course.KNO 
where 
     Course.Qualification='CCNA'
```

Comment: Kindly add the related tag, so that you are more chances of getting the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are having trouble writing a query sometimes it is helpful to mock it up using the Query Designer in Access and then see what SQL it produces. For your query:

[image: PersCourseWorked.png]

switching to SQL View reveals the following (reformatted for clarity):

```sql
SELECT Pers.KNO, Pers.Name, Pers.Company, Pers.Location, Pers.State
FROM 
    (
        Pers 
        LEFT JOIN 
        Course 
            ON Pers.KNO = Course.KNO
    ) 
    LEFT JOIN 
    Worked 
        ON Pers.KNO = Worked.KNO
WHERE (((Course.Qualification)="CCNA") AND ((Worked.Coyloc)="Bangalore")) 
    OR (((Course.Qualification)="CCNA") AND ((Worked.Coyloc)="Channai")) 
    OR (((Course.Qualification)="CCNA") AND ((Worked.Coyloc)="Kolkatta"));
```

Note that the parentheses in the FROM clause are important. Access is a bit fussy about that.

Other notes:

As you may have noticed, the WHERE clause could be reorganized as

```sql
WHERE Course.Qualification="CCNA"
    AND (Worked.Coyloc="Bangalore" OR Worked.Coyloc="Channai" OR Worked.Coyloc="Kolkatta")
```

Also, since you have specific WHERE conditions on columns in both the [Course] and [Worked] tables then you don't really need to use LEFT JOINs. INNER JOINs would have sufficed.

Comment: i tried the code above it works fine for me but when i added two more clauses to this one clause worked and other is not working what must be the probable cause please. the code i added is this:- AND ((Pers.Company) Not Like 'IMDT*' And (Pers.Company) Not Like 'EMIS*') AND ((Worked.Company) Not Like 'IMDT*' And (Worked.Company) Not Like 'EMIS*')). In this code Pers.Company is working fine but (Worked.Company) Not Like is not working for me. please guide me